# How to extract date and time using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is request I have

```
<test>
    <conversationId>495</conversationId>
    <conversation>
        <origination>DB</origination>
        <Content>
            <transactions>
                <merchantCountry>840</merchantCountry>
                <timestamp>2017-06-12T13:49:03.343Z</timestamp>

</test>
```

I need the `timestamp` value

```
Date=2017-06-12
time=13:49:03
```

I only need the HH:MM:SS doesn't need anything after.

**Expected output**

```
time=13:49:03
```

I have a solution however I am doing that using two variables

```
<xsl:variable name="time" select="/test/conversation/Content/transactions/timestamp"/>
    <xsl:variable name="timechange">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($time, 'T')"/>
            </xsl:variable>  
            <xsl:variable name="timechange1">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($timechange, '.')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
```

I was wondering if same can be done in single statement.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before($time, 'T'), '.')" /> but nothing came.
```

Updating:

```
"timestamp": "2017-07-12T13:49:03.343Z",
                "timestamp": "2017-07-12T13:49:03Z",
                "timestamp": "2017-07-12T13:49:03.343-00:05",
                "timestamp": "2017-07-12T13:49:03.343+00:15",
                "timestamp": "2017-07-12T13:49:03+01:05",
                "timestamp": "2017-07-12T13:49:03-01:05",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your substring-after should be substring-before and your substring-before should be substring-after.

Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before($time, 'T'), '.')" />
```

try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($time, 'T'), '.')" />
```

To handle dateTime's that don't contain `.`, add an additional concat...

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat(substring-after($time, 'T'),'.'), '.')" />
```

or use `substring()`...

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($time,12,8)" />
```

This will work with both `2017-06-12T13:49:03.343Z` and `2017-06-12T13:49:03`.

Comment: Thanks that was really silly mistake from my side. It's been long for me.

Comment: @Kumar_y - You're very welcome. Most of my mistakes are silly. :-)

Comment: I am trying to and I am getting an error stating wait for 5 min :(

Comment: can we just pass long the value if 2017-06-12T13:49:03 come like that?

Comment: @Kumar_y - Please see my edit. Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: I have just updated the format of timestamp which they can send and I just need HH:MM:SS

Comment: @Kumar_y - Please see my latest update using `substring()`.

Comment: Ha ha ha I just wrote the same thing :) :)